# Drawing a smooth and continuous Arc in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I tried the below code for drawing continuous arc to do a pie chart. The edges are not smooth if segments are given. If segments are given then there is a gap between the Arcs / Pie. Check the small area between Blue and grey. how to have a smooth edge and a continuous Arc ?

```
    game.shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,0,30);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,30,45);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BROWN);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,75,65);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,140,80);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,220,140);

    y=300;

    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,0,30,180);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,30,45,180);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BROWN);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,75,65,180);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,140,80,180);
    game.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    game.shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius,220,140,180);
    game.shapeRenderer.end();
```

[image]

Comment: I really do not know why the super powers are just down voting ? Would be good if they state the reason publically

Comment: I am also looking for this answer. Good if someone helps

Answer (score 0):

set samples config to high;

```
final LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.samples = 4;
```

Comment: I am using it in android.. Will it be applicable

Comment: AndroidApplicationConfiguration doesn't have "samples " method in it